# How to perform filtering in JS to fix browser freeze problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, foreach

I have a search box which filters data from the following array,

```
var arr = [
 {"unAssigned": { "ddlItems": [{label:L1u},{label:L2u}]}},
 {"EE01": { "ddlItems": [{label:L2e},{label:L3e},.......{label:L900e}]}},
 {"JobTitle": { "ddlItems": [{label:L1j},{label:L2j}]}},
 {"JobFunction": { "ddlItems": [{label:L1jf},{label:L2jf},....{label:L880jf]}},
 {"Manager": { "ddlItems": [{label:L1m},{label:L2m},...{label:L777m]}}
]
```

Function filtering array,

```
function filterBySearchText(searchString) {
    angular.forEach(_filters, function (filter) {
        angular.forEach(filter.ddlItems, function (ddlItem) {
            if ( ddlItem.label.indexOf(filterText) -1) {
                var result = {};
                angular.copy(ddlItem, result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Due to huge data present in 'ddlItems' ,the IE11 browser is getting locked and gets freezes. Is there any way to change the loop structure and make it work. Thanks.

Comment: `for` loop is a tiny bit faster... I guess that could help, even if only a little

Comment: Is there a way to restructure your view/filter so that you don't need to filter the whole dataset at once?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes